# What is the Galois group of the Hyperreal Numbers?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, real-numbers, nonstandard-analysis

The Galois Group of $\mathbb{R}$ as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.  That’s because any field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is order preserving, so since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that the only field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity.

But I don’t think $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the field of hyperreal numbers.  So my question is, what is the Galois group of the field of hyperreal numbers as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

I expect it to be a pretty large group, maybe something that involves a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: In fact, $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial field automorphisms at all: a nontrivial automorphism would have to either move $1$ or break the ordering. (Or, put another way, each individual rational is definable in $\mathbb{R}$ and so must be fixed by any automorphism.)

Comment: See also [Automorphisms of the hyperreals over the rationals and nontrivial automorphism groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258450/automorphisms-of-the-hyperreals-over-the-rationals-and-nontrivial-automorphism-g) on MathOverflow.